# dynamically change the colour of a table-hover in bootstrap based on a cell value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a simple table using `table-hover`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7o3qyb6/)

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Fleet</th>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">R132</th>
      <td>High St</td>
      <td>ON TIME</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">R100</th>
      <td>St Martins</td>
      <td>LATE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">W101</th>
      <td>Cafe St</td>
      <td>EARLY</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've found ways to change the default hover colour, and I can change the table row or cell background with the usual conditional formatting but that's not what I'm looking for.

e.g

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #color;
}
```

I'm trying to format the hover colour based on the value in the 'status' column with red for 'late' and green for 'early' etc. so that I can maintain the same look and feel of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add **class** to your **tr** indicating the color you want to see on hover

```css
.ontime:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.late:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.early:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Fleet</th>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ontime">
      <th scope="row">R132</th>
      <td>High St</td>
      <td>ON TIME</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="late">
      <th scope="row">R100</th>
      <td>St Martins</td>
      <td>LATE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="early">
      <th scope="row">W101</th>
      <td>Cafe St</td>
      <td>EARLY</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```